# Boost date/time microsec_clock not compiling correctly

Tags: c++, linux, boost-date-time

I'm trying to use the date/time facilities of the C++ Boost library v1.41.  (**Note**: this is Linux, not Windows; g++ v4.4.7)

Code:

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
using boost::posix_time::ptime;
using boost::date_time::microsec_clock;
 :
t1 = (boost::date_time::microsec_clock::local_time()); // line 208
```

The error:

```
tom.cpp:208: error: 'template<class time_type> class boost::date_time::microsec_clock' used without template parameters
```

Now, there's this in boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp:

```
#ifdef BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_HIGH_PRECISION_CLOCK
  //! A time clock that has a resolution of one microsecond
  /*! \ingroup time_basics
   */
  typedef date_time::microsec_clock<ptime> microsec_clock;
#endif
```

What I'm concluding is that BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_HIGH_PRECISION_CLOCK is undefined, resulting in the typedef never happening, resulting in the reference to "microsec_clock" looking like it needed a template parameter.

As far as I can tell, I'm following the [Boost date_time documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html#date_time.posix_time.ptime_class) to the letter.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could upgrade both `boost` and `g++`. Your versions are quite old!

Comment: If that is indeed the problem, I'm out of luck.  I may not have this exactly right, but CentOS provides packages of certain levels of software that it "approves": Boost is at its latest approved level, and g++ is at its latest 4.4.* version (and operations is leery to move beyond 4.4).  It's out of my hands - I've tried :-/

Comment: No, you can install (even inside your `$HOME/software/` directory) your own more recent versions of `boost` and `g++`.

Comment: Same problem after migrating from 1.55 to 1.64 .
Disapeared after including both headers:

    #include boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp
    #include boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_types.hpp

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem right now.
Yesterday it worked without any problems but today I needed to delete all my compiled libraries and recompile them due to a svn corruption problem. Ever since this error occurred.

The way to fix it is rather simple.
Just use

```
t1 = (boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time());
```

instead of

```
t1 = (boost::date_time::microsec_clock::local_time());
```

This will preset the time type to posix format however it will not fix the initial problem with BOOST_DATE_TIME_HAS_HIGH_PRECISION_CLOCK.

I hope this was of help to you.